# extract all the rows from one field then store in one row based on the name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

[image]

[image]

I want to store everything in column Lesion into one row.
Is it possible to do that?
How can I do that?

any advice would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
DECLARE @source TABLE ( name VARCHAR(100), lesion VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO @source(name , lesion)
VALUES ('Bob Desk', '123-456-7899'),
('Bob Desk', '123-456-7899'),
('Don Mouse', '123-456-5555'),
('Mike Keyboard', '123-456-7899'),
('Billy Power', '122-222-1134')



SELECT  DISTINCT name,STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + lesion
              FROM @source s
              WHERE s.name = s2.name
              FOR XML PATH ('')) 
             , 1, 1, '')

             FROM @source s2
```